GORM is not returning correct time.Time value for as Datetime type mysql column
Database is created by db.AutoMigrate(&models.User{})
User is in package: models
type User struct {
    Username     string         `json:"username" gorm:"primaryKey; not null; unique"`
    Passwordhash string         `json:"passwordhash" gorm:"not null"`
    Pincode      int            `json:"pincode" gorm:"not null"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time      `json:"created_at" gorm:"type:DATETIME"`
    UpdatedAt    time.Time      `json:"updated_at" gorm:"type:DATETIME"`
    DeletedAt    gorm.DeletedAt `json:"deleted_at" gorm:"index,type:DATETIME"`
}

    db := config.InitializeDB()
    var dataFromDB models.User //Read DB data from here
    errr := db.Where("username = ?", userData.Username).Limit(1).Find(&dataFromDB).Error
    log.Println("CreatedAt: ", dataFromDB.CreatedAt)
    log.Println("CreatedAt: ", dataFromDB.UpdatedAt)
    if errr != nil {
        log.Println("Error fetching data:", errr)
        return
    }

This is the complete error I am getting
2024/08/30 10:56:30 Server starting at 9090

2024/08/30 10:57:00 /app/controllers/auth_controller.go:30 sql: Scan error on column index 1, name "created_at": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *time.Time
[10.014ms] [rows:1] SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = 'smitesh97' AND `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL LIMIT 1
2024/08/30 10:57:00 CreatedAt:  0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2024/08/30 10:57:00 CreatedAt:  0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2024/08/30 10:57:00 Error fetching data: sql: Scan error on column index 1, name "created_at": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []uint8 into type *time.Time

This is part of a authentication backend I am trying to create as part of a group project. The main project will use this. Although when I use this config in my local setup it works. While running this on a container doesn't.
If I change the type of CreatedAt or UpdatedAt to type interface{}. It works just fine but I don't think thats recommended.
Is this a bug ?

Adding parseTime=True in DSN seems to have resolved the issue.
dsn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(host.docker.internal:3306)/lostandfound?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local", username, password)
    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    

